# Having a weird problem with particle system!

Tags: rendering, particles, instances

So, I've encountered a rather unusual problem with the Blender particle system. I've been using Blender for several years now, and working with particles is not new to me. I've attached some pictures at the end, which should provide a clear explanation. However, let's start with the version of Blender I'm currently using, which is Blender 3.6LTS.

The problem I'm facing is quite perplexing, as I haven't been able to find any similar issues or solutions online. While I can see the particles in the shaded and rendered views within the viewport, they simply don't appear in the final render. In my original project, I attempted various approaches, such as changing materials and baking the cache file, but none of them seem to work. I even tried creating a new file to replicate the particle setup, but the problem persists.

The project I'm currently working on holds great significance, and I'd prefer not to switch to an entirely different version of Blender, as that would introduce a whole new set of challenges, including the installation of plugins and registering file paths.

I've included the attached pictures for reference. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Shaded View
[image: shaded view]

Viewport Render View
[image: viewport render view]

Render Output
[image: render output]

Particles Settings
[image: particles settings]

Update:

Blend file: https://www.transfernow.net/dl/blender-stack-exchange

Comment: Could it possibly be that the render view toggle on the individual particle system was turned off?

Comment: no, it was not!

Comment: pls provide blend file since we have nearly no information about your whole setup (including materials) except particle settings. thx.

Comment: The Blender version your currently using is 3.6LTS...? Which one, 3.6.5 / 3.6.4 / 3.6.3 / 3.6.2 / 3.6.1? Anyway, should work in all of these... I agree with @Chris that we need your file. I just recreated this on my PC with 3.6.4 and the particles look exactly the same like yours, same size and distribution and they get rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your replies I'll be adding the file shortly.

Comment: Guys I've uploaded the blend on a file transferring web and provided the link at the bottom line.

Comment: which frame did u try to render? since your particles are falling down, at a later frame you might not see any particles. I cleared the render region you set and if i render i see this:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MihS3.png ...so looks ok for me

Comment: i tried rendering num 1 frame usually I make the gravity field 0 and then render but I guess I forgot to do that for this. and you can see in my render output file there's nothing anywhere.

Comment: figured it out guys, just have to render it on the 2nd frame and that's all for some reason I don't know, well it's working at least. even so if someone could figure it out why cant I render on 1st frame as I could do so in past.

Comment: @MDRAFI Well, it's not really working... on frame 2 the particles already moved a bit upwards because they have a normal velocity of 1 m/s. I deleted the plane, the icosphere, the particle system, made everything new - same problem. I make a full copy of the scene, same problem. I make a fresh new scene in the same file and built everything new - it works from frame 1 on. So there must be something wrong with your scene settings, I just couldn't find it yet.